# How to set Tiered Pricing on Configurable Products using Price Rules

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, tierprice, price-rules, magento-2.0.2

All of my googling tells me that Magento 2 no longer supports price tiers for configurable products. Only simple products can have price tiers.

The results also point me to using Price Rules.

How do I setup MARKETING > Catalog Price Rule(s) to get price tiers at different order quantities?

The pages are not very intuitive and I cannot find how to set quality break points.

Comment: You  can set tiers for associated simple product

Answer (score 0):

We can still setup tiers price for configurable products when we create new product, but we cant edit it later.

-Go to Admin-Product-Catalog: add new configurable product

-In base setting-product details tab: fill name, sku, price then SAVE

-Now u can see advanced pricing in advanced setting tab

[image]

Comment: Is it working for `Configurable` Products?

Answer (score 0):

You can still create configurable products with tier prices, but configurable product can use only swatches or dropdowns.

1. Create configurable product
2. input one price - for now , name and sku
3. go down to configuration tab
   generate configurable products using attributes that you can select from there
   (they need to be layered navigation(in results))
4. click done
   5 you can choice now each of generated products and applay tired price
5. save configurable product